# Kubernetes Kube error in master Kube_Client_Errors

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I need to create some technote on this alert KubeClientErrors to fix the issue, So please help on this.

```
Description:-KubernetesAPI serverclientisexperiencingerrors.
```

Thanks in advance

Regards,

Ravi

Comment: The question isn't clear. Can you provide more context?

Comment: Hi All,

Detail description of the alert which we have received, So please help on this

Labels:
- alertname = KubeClientErrors
- instance = 10.0.0.0:1000
- job = kubelet
- prometheus = monitoring/k8s
- severity = 2
Annotations:
- message = Kubernetes API server client 'kubelet/10.0.0.0:1000' is experiencing 58% errors.'